# How does dark energy affect the dynamics of galaxy clusters?

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, space-expansion, dark-energy, galaxy-clusters

Galaxies interact with each other gravitationally (just as every other celestial object) and in many cases they form groups or clusters.

Does the expansion of the universe (or dark energy) affect the interaction of galaxies in some way and therefore the dynamics of clusters?

Comment: Galaxies are complicated things, so the three-body problem doesn't apply.

Comment: The three-body problem is not relevant to galaxies. Are you trying to ask how dark energy affects the dynamics of galaxy clusters?

Comment: @Sten I thought it would apply since I have read some abstracts linking the three-body problem to galaxies... but perhaps I misinterpreted them. Then, does dark energy (or the expansion of the universe) affects the dynamics of clusters in some way?

Answer (score 3):

Systems of orbiting material exceed the cosmological average density by a factor of around 200 (the "[virial overdensity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_mass)"). So dark energy makes only a percent-level contribution to the dynamics within galaxy clusters. Its influence can be understood as an effective reduction in the mass of the cluster for objects orbiting at large distances, so that they orbit slightly more slowly. This effect is small enough that I doubt it has ever been searched for.

A much more clearly measurable effect of dark energy is its influence on the *assembly* of galaxy clusters. Instead of orbiting material, this effect concerns the material that is still on its first infall into the cluster. Dark energy slows that infall, and this effect can be measured via galaxy redshifts. (The effect of infall on redshifts is known as the Kaiser effect; see [redshift-space distortions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redshift-space_distortions).)

Indeed the slowing of the assembly of galaxy clusters is one way to verify that accelerated expansion really results from dark energy and not, for example, from a modification to gravity (see for example section 4 of [this recent review](https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.05003)). It's easy for modified gravity theories to reproduce the observed cosmic expansion history but more difficult for them to reproduce both that and the large-scale structure growth rate.

Comment: and can dark energy affect outflows of galaxies so that the ejected material would fall again into the galaxy (by gravitational attraction) at a greater distance than it would do without dark energy? @Sten

Comment: @vengaq Outflows would be affected -- they would travel farther from their sources and potentially become unbound more easily. I don't know enough about outflows to say much more, though.

Comment: Hard as it is, wouldn't it be easier to find percent-level effects in galaxy clusters than to record and calibrate many supernovas at z > 1 ? Also, has Kaiser effect been observed at a precision that would allow a dark energy contribution to be seen?

Comment: @AndrewSteane Beyond being a percent-level effect, dark energy is also partially degenerate with cluster masses. As discussed in [the subsequent question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/782098/180843), that can be accounted for to still estimate the amount of dark energy, although the linked papers focus on MW-M31 which is still on first infall. Kaiser effect gives much better precision; I'm not up-to-date on the literature but see fig. 8 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.2948 or fig. 5 of the review linked in the answer. $f$ is the logarithmic derivative of the linear growth function.

Comment: Note that in a flat cosmology without dark energy, $f=1$ and $\sigma_8\propto 1/(1+z)$, which is already clearly not the case in those figures. I haven't looked at what is the growth function in an open cosmology without dark energy, but you could derive it easily from equation (4) of the review.

Comment: This dissertation (https://louis.uah.edu/uah-dissertations/31/) seems to indicate that dark energy makes bound systems "less bounded" and thus larger orbits. Could dark energy make a bound system (like a large galaxy or a satellite galaxy orbiting a bigger one) be "less bounded" so that orbits towards the central point of mass are larger?

And if dark energy would help to make orbits be further away from the central point of mass, does it mean that dark energy could add orbital energy to bodies orbiting the center of the galaxy at the outskirts of it? @Sten

Comment: @vengaq Dark energy would indeed make orbits less bound and larger. I'm not sure I would describe this as adding orbital energy, though. The reference for potential energy is actually ambiguous in a universe with dark energy (because potential diverges to negative infinity at infinite distance), and at least the orbital kinetic energy is not increased by dark energy.

Answer (score 0):

Dark energy may be very important when considering the dynamics of clusters at large radii.

The dark energy density has an anti-gravitational affect and since the dark energy density is uniform, then the affective anti-gravitational mass will grow as the cube of the radius encompassed. Since the mass of matter (both dark and baryonic) is centrally concentrated, then it grows less quickly with growing radius.

A paper by [Chernin et al. (2013)](https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/full_html/2013/05/aa20781-12/aa20781-12.html) studies the Coma cluster in this context. They show that the anti-gravitational mass contained within a sphere grows from $-2\times10^{12} M_\odot$ at $R=1.4$ Mpc to $-2\times 10^{15}M_\odot$ at $R=14$ Mpc.

The contribution of dark energy to the net gravitational mass is negligible at the smaller radius but reduces the net gravitational mass by about 50% at the larger radius. Chernin et al. conclude that the mass inferred from the dynamics of galaxies *in the outer part of the cluster*, where dark energy is important, is a lower limit to the actual mass of matter in the cluster, because of the anti-gravity effects of dark energy.

[Merafina et al. (2014)](https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/full_html/2014/08/aa24062-14/aa24062-14.html) treat such a system using a modified version of the Poisson equation
$$\nabla^2 \Phi = 4\pi G\rho_m - \Lambda c^2\ , $$
where $\Lambda$ is the cosmological constant. They show that the equilibrium configurations in galaxy clusters become more extended with $\Lambda > 0$, where again, the effects become apparent on radius scales of
$$ r \sim \left(\frac{3GM_r}{\Lambda c^2}\right)^{1/3}\ , $$
where $M_r$ is the mass of matter within that radius.

Comment: So if Dark Energy extends the equilibrium configurations does that mean that orbits are extended in their radius? @ProfRob

Comment: @vengaq For a given amount of mass interior to the orbit and a virialised kinetic energy then the orbital radius would be larger.