# Dark energy, bound systems and orbits...?

Tags: gravity, astrophysics, space-expansion, galaxies, dark-energy

As far as I understand it, dark energy can affect bound systems at cosmological scales ([How does dark energy affect the dynamics of galaxy clusters?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/781404/how-does-dark-energy-affect-the-dynamics-of-galaxy-clusters)) effectively modifying their orbits.

This phenomenon and this [thesis dissertation](https://louis.uah.edu/uah-dissertations/31/) made me wonder...

Could dark energy make a bound system (like a large galaxy or a satellite galaxy orbiting a bigger one) be "less bound" so that the orbits respective to the central point of mass are larger?

And if dark energy would help to make orbits be further away from the central point of mass, does it mean that dark energy could add orbital energy to bodies orbiting the center of the galaxy at the outskirts of it?

Comment: Are you asking if this happens in principle, or if it's big enough to be seen in practice?

Comment: @knzhou rather if it happens in principle or in theory...

Comment: How does this differ from your previous question? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/781404/how-does-dark-energy-affect-the-dynamics-of-galaxy-clusters?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @ProfRob on my previous question I was asking if dark energy affects in some way the dynamics of orbiting galaxies. Now I am asking a more specific question, namely if dark energy makes these orbits bigger adding orbital energy to the system