# Does the accelerated expansion of the universe have any effects in the orbital precession of galaxies? And in their eccentricity?

Tags: orbital-motion, space-expansion, galaxies, dark-energy, precession

I found several papers (https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/2041-8213/ace90b; https://link.springer.com/article/10.1134/S1063772920100054; https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0301057; https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6289) where the authors indicate a relation between dark energy and orbital precession (even one of them makes the assertion that this is a widely accepted phenomenon).

But as far as I know, dark energy has no effect for gravitationally bound bodies. So how can it have any effect in their orbital precession?

Also, I showed this paper (https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/2041-8213/ace90b) to a physicist in another physics-discussion forum, and while discussing if the precession caused by dark energy also affected the eccentricity of orbits, he told me:

> It appears that dark energy causes a precession term, which makes sense since gravity causes a precession term, the famous precession of Mercury, and they both bend space, causing things to precess, increasing their eccentricity. This effect should be negligible for objects deep within gravitational potentials; planets orbiting a star or a star orbiting within a galaxy, but should become larger as distances increase and objects become more loosely bound to each other and emerge in the interactions between galaxies where gravity and dark energy approach parity with each other.

Then does it mean that this precession contributed by dark energy also increases the eccentricty of galaxies orbiting other galaxies in clusters (at sufficiently far distances)?

Comment: Galaxies don't expand with the expansion of the universe. See this Veritasium video. [What Actually Expands In An Expanding Universe?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9DrBQg_n2Uo)

Comment: @mmesser314 but these are not saying that galaxies expand with the universe, rather asking if their orbits are affected by it. It's like when astrophysicists indicate that galaxies' orbits in clusters are a bit extended in a dark energy dominated universe than in one without expansion.

Comment: Seems to be one of a series of similar questions: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/781404/how-does-dark-energy-affect-the-dynamics-of-galaxy-clusters